# Can I get my Battle.Net authenticator to accept one-button approval instead of codes?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, battle.net

If I log into the Blizzard website, or for some games, I can get the authenticator to pop up a request that I just have to approve or deny, to be able to log in.

However, I've noticed that for WoW, when I log in, it only allows me to enter the code manually, not use the one button "approve/deny" system.

I tried looking at the settings, but the only thing I could really find that I could change was the "ask for a code every time I log in" option, which seems to just change it from "every time" to "once a week" - but by the sounds of it, I'd still have to type in the code by hand.

I find this frustrating as it usually takes a number of tries as I am not always as quick as it wants me to be, so the codes keep changing, whereas with the one button option, I'd be able to authenticate much easier.

Is there a way to set it up so I don't have to enter the code each time?

Comment: I'm confused... WoW usually doesn't ask for a login because you're already logged in to the Blizzard launcher.

Comment: @Powerlord It asks me relatively often for it. I'd not be asking if it didn't. I don't know if it is because I've noticed the launcher is weird about detecting if I am online, or what, but it asks me for it every couple days at least.

Comment: [Apparently there were some bugs with the one-button authentification](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/20765076808#post-9). Also IIRC most games themselves don't support the one-button authentification but as @Powerlord said: If you're already logged in in the launcher you shouldn't be asked for another code.

Comment: I shouldn't be, but I often am. Like I can be chatting with someone through the launcher, and still be asked for a code when I launch WoW.

Comment: Being logged in to the launcher does nothing directly AFAIK. Only if you're logged in and click the button to get to your account management you shouldn't be asked for a code again. Other than that I never get asked for a code when I launch WoW from the launcher.

Comment: Try the mobile authenticator app instead. You can just tap Approve and go.

Comment: @MichaelHampton My entire problem is that the mobile authenticator app doesn't give me the tap to approve option for WoW.

Comment: That's bizarre. Mine has been giving me the option for months now.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do I have to specifically tell it to do so somewhere or something that I might have missed? It does it for Battle.net and Hearthstone, but WoW is always the codes.

Comment: Not that I've ever seen.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Curiouser and curiouser. I wonder why it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get "One-Button Approval" in the WoW client. It only supports this through the Battle.net Launcher, which will only ask you the first time. When launching the WoW client directly (so not from the launcher), or when you are returned to the login screen (for example, on a disconnect), the client will ask you for an authenticator code. This is because the client does not support the authenticator in its modern shape (e.g. one-button approval).

What I found is an acceptable work-around, is to just close the client and launch it from the Battle.net Launcher. Depending on your system, this may not be optimal.

If this does not work for you, and you are asked for an authenticator code even when launching from Battle.net launcher, you should try removing and adding the mobile authenticator in your account's security settings. You can find out how to do so by viewing the support article on [Removing the Blizzard Authenticator](https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/118903) and [Blizzard Authenticator](https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/24520).

When that does not help resolve your issue, I strongly recommend you [contact Blizzard](https://us.battle.net/support/en/help), as there will be definitely be a technical issue at play. In my experience, their support department is very helpful and quick to respond.